# syntax error in mortal fibonacci rabbit program in haskell

Tags: haskell, fibonacci, ghci

I have a problem in making mortal-fibonacci rabbit program in haskell.
the word mortal means 'the rabbit died after 3 months when it was born'

here's my haskell code

```
mortalRabbits xs 0 = xs
mortalRabbits xs n = mortalRabbits xs' (n-1)
where xs' = updateRabbits xs

updateRabbits (x:xs) = 
    case x of
        0 = [1] ++ updateRabbits xs
        1 = [2, 0] ++ updateRabbits xs
        2 = [3, 0] ++ updateRabbits xs
        3 = [] ++ updateRabbits xs
```

and the ghci keep print "num2.hs:3:1: parse error on input 'where'" and refuse to load my code.

so i remove the line 'where xs' = updateRabbits xs' 
and change the line 2 to 'mortalRabbits xs n = mortalRabbits (updateRabbits) (n-1)'.

but this time, the ghci keep print "num2.hs:7:19: parse error on input '='.

I think these two errors are kinda same situation.
I'm a new-born baby in haskell area. so could u tell me what's going on in it?
btw srry for my poor Eng.

Comment: Use `->`, not `=`, between cases and their clauses.

Comment: I changed '=' to '->' in case expression, but the result was same.

Comment: srry it's a typing mistake. I edit it now..

Comment: @Cho4sure You need to indent that `where` further.

Comment: `where` on line 3 needs to be indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your reference, here is the syntax fixed version of your code:

```
mortalRabbits xs 0 = xs
mortalRabbits xs n = mortalRabbits xs' (n-1)
  where xs' = updateRabbits xs

updateRabbits (x:xs) = 
    case x of
        0 -> [1] ++ updateRabbits xs
        1 -> [2, 0] ++ updateRabbits xs
        2 -> [3, 0] ++ updateRabbits xs
        3 -> [] ++ updateRabbits xs
```

Comment: thanx bro. I changed entire interface btw..  anyway thanx for ur help!